# Dropdown menu list from sqlite database table

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, phonegap

Am trying to get data from an sqlite database table to feed to my dropdown menu list. See my thinking below. The problem is I don’t know how to marry the JS function with the HTML part.

HTML.html

```
    <label for="name"><b>Activity Name:/b></label>          
    <select name="activity" id="activity" required>
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        getActivity()
    </select>
```

JS.js

```
    function getActivity(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tblactivity', [], queryActivity, errorHandler);
                function queryActivity(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
               var SelectActivity +='<option value="' + results.rows.item(i).activityID +'">'+ results.rows.item(i).ActivityName +'</Option>';
            }
            //SelectActivity +="</Option";
            document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML =SelectActivity;
        }}
```

Alternatively on HTML.html, incorporating the Function like

```
    <label for="name"><b>Activity Name:/b></label>          
    <select name="activity" id="activity" required>
    <script>
        function getActivity(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tblactivity', [], queryActivity, errorHandler);
                function queryActivity(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
               var SelectActivity +='<option value="' + results.rows.item(i).activityID +'">'+ results.rows.item(i).ActivityName +'</Option>';
            }
            //SelectActivity +="</Option";
            document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML =SelectActivity;
        }}
    </script>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the options on load I would recommend wrapping your js in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your function
});
```

This way it will run after the HTML has been loaded, and you don't need to do anything in the HTML side (meaning you should remove you call to your function).

EDIT: That solution is JQuery, if you want a pure JS approach use:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //your function
};
```

Keep in mind this one will load everything before running, like images and other media; on slower connections users may see an empty select before they get loaded.

EDIT (after comments):
Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chn1oL8m/5/
I think I understood your problem now, and this will help you out, just need to use the query instead of random values (I don't have access to the DB obviously =] )

Comment: I have already enabled the on load functions on the extended code (left out code). The question is clear on what I seek but thanks!

Comment: Hi @mountain, I might be missing something, but if this is not what you're looking for I didn't understand what it is. Could you explain it differently, maybe I can help you.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't suggest the solution implementation. Both the JS and HTML are not working, that was just an implementation guide.

Comment: I've edited the answer once again, hopefully you get it to work now!

Comment: Looked at that, Still the login is bad. The solution has to start from  function getActivity(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tblactivity', [], queryActivity, errorHandler);
          function queryActivity(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
               var activity +='<option value="' + results.rows.item(i).activityID +'">'+ results.rows.item(i).ActivityName +'</Option>';
    }
   }
  }


If I can get the JS part at least

Comment: window.onload = function() {
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
   Squery = 'SELECT * FROM tblactivity';
   tx.executeSql(Squery,null,function(tx, results)
    {
    var select = document.getElementById('activity');
    var len = results.rows.length;
     for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
     row = results.rows.item(i);
     var ID = row['activityID'];
     var Name = row['ActivityName'];
     var opt = document.createElement('option');
     opt.value = ID;
     opt.innerHTML = Name;
     select.appendChild(opt);
     }
    });
   });
  };

Comment: still cant get it to work. Look above comment and see where we can improve. Your jsfiddle has empty select list.